# Angular setting input type="date" at start at actual date

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following code and i want to get the input to start with the the actual date

```
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
      <label class="form-label" for="enroll"><b>User Enrollement Date</b></label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" required [form-control]="EnrollmentDate"/>
</div>
```

in component.ts i have the following:

```
export class AppComponent {
  EnrollementDate = new FormControl(new Date());
```

How i can start the date input like this:
[image]
instead of this:
[image]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to bind the formControl to a formControl and not to a ngModel

```
<div class="form-outline mb-4">
      <label class="form-label" for="enroll"><b>User Enrollement Date</b></label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" required [formControl]="EnrollmentDate"/>
</div>
```

Also the input is always working with string so you have also to do it like that:

```
EnrollmentDate = new FormControl(new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10));
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdstvv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: updated in the question thanks,but it doesn't solve the question.

Comment: @Blackhole i also updated my anwser

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateValue = 'Jun 15, 2015, 21:43:11 UTC'; // UTC format works best

EnrollementDate = new FormControl(new Date(dateValue));
```

The above should work, if you want to set it during OnInit lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.EnrollementDate.setValue(dateValue or new Date(dateValue));
}
```